# Disable hockey for app store version

Tags: ios, hockeyapp

I don't want to include hockey sdk in my app store version. As a result, I create two target and for app store target, I don't include hockey sdk. In my app delegate, I write like this.

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#import <HockeySDK/HockeySDK.h>
#elif RELEASE
#import <HockeySDK/HockeySDK.h>
#elif DEVHOCKEY
#import <HockeySDK/HockeySDK.h>
#endif
if (ENV == ENV_DEV || ENV == ENV_PROD_WITH_DEV_HOCKEY || ENV == ENV_PROD) {
    [[BITHockeyManager sharedHockeyManager] configureWithIdentifier:HOCKEY_KEY];
    [[BITHockeyManager sharedHockeyManager] startManager];
    [[BITHockeyManager sharedHockeyManager].authenticator authenticateInstallation];
    [[BITHockeyManager sharedHockeyManager].feedbackManager setFeedbackObservationMode:BITFeedbackObservationModeThreeFingerTap];
}
else if (ENV == ENV_APPSTORE) {

}
```

Problem is that when I run or archive for app store target, it say "Use of undeclared identifier BITHockeyManager". How shall I do to exclude hockey sdk and their code only for app store version?

Comment: Any specific reasons you don't want to use crash reporting in the App Store build?

Comment: I think for crash reporting, user will see prompt and ask whether they want to send. I don't want to show that prompt and currently, I am already using flurry. I use hockey to distribute for internal testers.

Comment: You can disable the prompt, see the documentation: http://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/app-management-2/how-to-auto-submit-crash-reports I suggest you try out the crash reporting feature and compare it to see which is better :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not correct to exclude a lib in this way. In order to get the Complier work for your code, you need to always import HockeySDK/HockeySDK.h.

I have two suggestions to meet your requirements:

Solotion 1: Build two separate apps, one for pre-release test which can distributed via HockeyApp; the other for Apple Store Release without importing HockeyApp.

Solution 2: Keep one build with HockeyApp integrated. The HockeyApp SDK should check for the existence of a provisioning profile in the App bundle to detect the AppStore environment and then automatically disables all beta only features of HockeyApp. (i.e. "In-App-Updates" in the  iOS SDK (for Beta & Enterprise only) are automatically disabled when running in an App Store build by default. You can refer [here](http://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/app-management-2/how-to-organize-development-and-production-apps-for-distribution#hockeyapp-offers-four-pre-defined-release-types-) for more information.